# Помогите спарсить данные со страницы

Tags: python-3.x, requests

Пожалуйста, помогите получить со страницы количество результатов. Обычный парсинг не работает, так как страница запускает JS-скрипты и отправляет ajax-запросы. Я реализовал код на Python с помощью selenium. Но это очень медленно. Хотелось бы парсить данные с помощью запросов. Пишите ваш код на Python, пожалуйста.

Сайт для парсинга: [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://search.rsl.ru/ru/search#q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: А что парсить то нужно? По Вашей ссылке нет результатов.

Comment: @nomnoms12 получить нужно количество результатов. Там написано: 0 результатов. Их и надо получить. Если там будет написано, что найдено 329 329 результатов, то получить это значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы получить нужные Вам данные, необходимо отправить `POST`-запрос на адрес `https://search.rsl.ru/site/ajax-search`.

Но не всё так просто. Методом научного тыка я выяснил, что запрос также требует `cookies` и следующие заголовки:

```py
'X-CSRF-Token'
'Content-Type'
```

Если со 2-ым всё просто, то 1-ый вместе с `cookies` ещё нужно как-то получить.
Для этого я предварительно устанавливаю сессию со страницей поиска и паршу её.

Остаётся лишь сформировать данные для запроса, как минимум, - строку, по который мы ищем.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json


def main() -> None:
    session = requests.Session()

    html = session.get('https://search.rsl.ru/ru/search').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    csrf = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'csrf-token'})['content']

    url = r'https://search.rsl.ru/site/ajax-search?language=ru'
    headers = {
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrf,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    }
    data = {
        'SearchFilterForm[search]': 'stackoverflow',
    }
    r = session.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

    d = json.loads(r.text)
    print(d['TotalHits'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Данные вернутся в виде `json`, нужный нам ключ - `TotalHits`.
Например, по запросу `stackoverflow` вернётся `60` результатов.

***stdout:***

```html
60
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @ДаняПавлюк Если ответ помог Вам, то пометьте его как правильный, пожалуйста.